# Regarding hardware requirements for freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I have a ubuntu 16.04 desktop version installed on 64 bit 4GB RAM, intel core i3 processor 2.13 GHz.

I need to install freeswitch for doing a small project. It will take only one call at a time. I tried looking up the hardware requirements for freeswitch on their wiki. But i am not able to find the hardware requirements.

Will freeswitch run fine on my laptop? Is there a page giving details about minimum  hardware requirements for freeswitch? Thanks.

Update: I got some more info on another website: Section Hardware and Software Requirements [freeswitch versus asterisk](http://www.whichvoip.com/freeswitch-vs-asterisk.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Min Requirement](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Specifications)

[System Tuning](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Performance_testing_and_configurations)

Minimum/Recommended System Requirements:

32-bit OS (64-bit recommended)

512MB RAM (1GB recommended)

50MB of Disk Space

System requirements depend on your deployment needs.

If you just want group video calling feature then go for 1.6.x version, else just use only 1.4.x